# How can I code my web page to download a file from a site visitor's computer?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, download, appdata

I am creating a html5 and javascript web page that allows you to draw your own picture. The page itself works, but I want to make it so my web application will create a folder in their Appdata (or Application Data if they're on a mac) directory.

Then I also want to make it so when a user logs back on to the website, all of their work is saved and they can pick up where they left off.

So basically, I want to be able to create a file on a client's directory, then be able to download that file once they have saved a change to their drawing. Is there a way I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with storing it in the browser's IndexedDB or even just localStorage? You can create a downloadable link if you'd like no problem.

Answer (score 0):

[All of these things can be done by using the HTML5 file APIs.](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)
Here are some links which will help you with your task:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/file_access

Storing state can be accomplished by using one of the following technologies:

- [Cookies](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/2010/09/ClientSideStorage.html)
- [`localStorage`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/)
- [`indexeddb`](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/)
- [WebSQL](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/)